# IntelliJ only reformats code if I select it (for Scala)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've this problem, that's different from the behaviour I'm used to, that consists in intelliJ only formatting code if I select it. Usually if nothing is selected it will reformat the entire file. But it appears not to do it anymore.

This is happening in Scala

Comment: I never have this problem using IntelliJ Ultimate on Ubuntu 18.04... Have you contacted JetBrains support about this?

Comment: This problem doesn't happen with me. it reformat the entire class for me. what Intellij version are you using?